# OpenCv in C : Image structure empty at the exit of pipe

Tags: c, opencv

i try to film with my webcam and get frame to send them into a pipe. First i have just tried to take only one picture and send it.
I send into the pipe a pointeur of the structure picture
But the pointeur of the structure was full at the entrance of the pipe but is empty at the exit.

I have looked for solution about send structure in pipe, and i read that i have to initialize a pointeur of the structure picture with malloc before reading the exit.I try it but this not work.

This the documentation of the structure of the image that i use with opencv :

http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d6/d5b/structIplImage.html#a004c6e47e73b4196d019e935620448e9

I compile with this commande :

```
gcc -ggdb `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -o `basename opencv_v3.c .c` opencv_v3.c `pkg-config --libs opencv`
```

And i have this result :

```
open webcam 
take picture

size struct : 144        
size picture : 921600

send picture
receive picture

size struct : -1386173560
size picture : 0
```

this is my code :

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int take_picture(CvCapture *capture,int fd[]){

   IplImage* img = cvQueryFrame(capture);

    printf("take picture\n\n");

    printf("size struct : %d\n",img->nSize);
    printf("size picture : %d\n\n",img->imageSize);

    close(fd[0]);
    write(fd[1], img,img->nSize);
    close(fd[1]);

    printf("send picture\n");

   return img->nSize;
}



void reception(int fd[],int size){

  IplImage* img = malloc(size);

  close(fd[1]);
  read(fd[0],img,size);
  close(fd[0]);

  printf("receive picture\n\n");

  printf("size struct : %d\n",img->nSize);
  printf("size picture : %d\n\n",img->imageSize);

 free(img);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

   int fd[2];
   int size;
   int pid;

   if (pipe(fd) == -1){
      printf("pipe failed\n");
      return -1;
   }

   if((pid = fork()) < 0){
     printf("fork failed\n");
     return -1;
   }

   if (pid == 0){
      /* child */
      printf("open webcam \n");
      CvCapture *capture=cvCreateCameraCapture(0);
      size = take_picture(capture,fd);

   }        
   else{
      /* parent */
      waitpid(pid,0,WUNTRACED);
      reception(fd,size);
   }

   return 0;
 }
```